# How to count the number of elements in all Oracle varrays from table?

Tags: oracle, count, spatial, varray

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE spatial_data (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  geometry SDO_GEOMETRY);
```

SDO_GEOMETRY has a field sdo_ordinates with the following type:

TYPE SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY AS VARRAY(1048576) OF NUMBER

I can get the number of points for specified object:

```
select count(*)
from table(
    select s.geometry.sdo_ordinates
    from spatial_data s
    where s.id = 12345
);
```

How can I get count for several objects? It's not possible to use

```
where s.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

And I really care about performance. Maybe PL/SQL would be the right choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you can do it with one query:

```
select s.id, count(*)
  from spatial_data s, table(s.geometry.sdo_ordinates)
 group by s.id
```

or you can write a plsql simple function that returns the count attribute of the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY VARRAY:

```
create or replace function get_count(ar in SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY) return number is
begin
   return ar.count;
end get_count;
```

or even nicer add a member function to SDO_GEOMETRY TYPE which return the count attribute

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've compared these two queries and the second approach with pl/sql function works much faster.