# Get length of oracle.sql.array

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle

On an Oracle DB I have a table with SDO_GEOMETRY objects. I would like to query the database for those polygons with less than x edges. In theory this would be easy with a query like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE LENGTH(t.geometry.sdo_ordinates) < x
```

Obviously the LENGTH funtion is defined for char and the type of 
`t.geometry.sdo_ordinates` is oracle.sql.ARRAY so that doesn't work. Shouldn't there be a trivial way to SELECT the length or an array in Oracle? Somehow I'm unable to get the syntax right.

PS: I kind of solved my search with the following query, still the original questerion remains, isn't there an array size/length function?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE LENGTH(t.geomety.Get_WKT()) < (x * c)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use: `t.geometry.sdo_ordinates.COUNT` ?

Comment: Yes, I actually tried `t.geometry.sdo_ordinates.COUNT` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no simple sql function that counts the elements of an array.

However as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974900/1309035), another idea is a PL/SQL script.

```
create or replace function get_count(ar in SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY) return number is
begin
   return ar.count;
end get_count;
```

---

`t.geometry.sdo_ordinates.COUNT` is a PL/SQL [**attribute**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i11073) that can be used *within* functions/procedures. Thus that is **not a function useable in plain SQL**.

Attribute:

```
value.someAttribute
```

Function:

```
doSomething(value)
```

Clarification: Functions have return values, procedures don't. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771949/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql)